# MS Access : On Exit Command ''Select No" when asked if user wants to save the changes

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2007, ms-access-2010

I have a navigation Form with subforms linked to it , this subforms are basically used to filter data , my problem is this : when navigating through the forms (after using the Filter) i get asked by MS Access if I want to save my changes.I would like to get rid of this question. Any Ideas on how I could do this? I guess I would need to use some Macro in the "on Exit" Field ,but my programming knowledge is limited :)

Br,

Comment: Show your existing code.

Comment: I found this comand `Private Sub NavigationButton7_Exit(Cancel As Integer)  
DoCmd.SetWarnings False
End Sub` this is not ideal because it cancels all warnings , I would like this to apply only to the Filter Navigation Form.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure why you are getting this. This prompt should only occur when you go from form view mode in to design view, which the user should not be doing.
Opening a form in view mode-changing filter-closing form- in view mode only should not return this save option.